# Obtener los valores que se encuentran por arriba de una diagonal, la principal especificamente

Tags: python

Como puedo obtener los valores que se encuentran por arriba de la diagonal principal utilizando anidadas??

Revise diferentes métodos desde numpy hasta la definición de una variable, no se si hay una manera más sencilla y menos tediosa de hacerlo, pero trate de obtener los valores por arriba de la diagonal principal por columna ponerlos en una lista e ir eliminando los que no eran necesarios.

Con este condigo yo obtuve la diagonal principal de la matriz:

```
def printDiagnol(lst): 
      

    print('Diagnol Principal - ', end ="") 
    print([lst[i][i] for i in range(len(lst))]) 
      
lst = [[61, 19, 89, 75, 45], 
       [ 2, 82, 59, 38, 68], 
       [74, 40, 35,10, 13], 
       [61, 27, 25, 84, 28], 
       [42, 43, 4, 79, 14]] 
printDiagnol(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

Las valores arriba de la diagonal cumplen la condición de que indice de columna es mayor a su indice de fila.

El método es recorrer por fila, y en cada fila, listar los valores comenzando de la columna "fila+1".

Utilizando `for` anidados:

```
def printDiagnol(lst):
    for fila in range(len(lst)):
        for columna in range(fila+1, len(lst)):
            print(lst[fila][columna], end=" ")
        print()
```

produce:

```
19 89 75 45 
59 38 68 
10 13 
28
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues las diagonal superior, no es más que la diagonal principal, desplazada una posición, por lo que podrías generalizar una solución como la siguiente:

```
def diagonal(lst, despl=0):
  start = 0 if despl >= 0 else 0 - despl
  return [lst[x][x+despl] for x in range(start, len(lst)-(abs(despl)-start))]
```

Ejemplo:

```
print(diagonal(lst, 1))

[19, 59, 10, 28]
```

Por otro lado, con `numpy` puedes resolverlo con [`diagonal()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(lst)

print(A.diagonal(1))

[19 59 10 28]
```